# clear stack without calling startActivity()

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm on a certain Activity & I want to clear the all the previous stack if a certain condition is true.

```
if (condition_is_true) {
// Clear stack
}
```

I can't use:

1. Because, I want to check the condition first

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".CurrentActivity"
       android:noHistory="true" />
   ```
2. Because, I don't want to start a new activity

   ```
   Intent nextIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,
                                  NextActivity.class);
   nextIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                     | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
   startActivity(nextIntent);
   ```

Comment: Whats the use case ? Why can't you go with `startActivity` approach.

Comment: have you tried Intent int = getIntent() and then set the same flags?

Comment: @Deepakkaku Nothing happens after getIntent() & setting the same flags. I need to call startActivity() to clear the stack. So my problem is not solved